# Leaflet: summary many markers

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have many markers (10,000) to show in a leaflet project targeting mobile. I do not thing I should load the full dataset in the app, but should instead only show the detail that is needed.

Is there a best practice in leaflet for having this incremental rendering?

Comment: I'm a JavaScript Programmer that has never used `Leaflet`, but have used Google Maps. It looks pretty cool. I say customize everything, according to zoom and all that. Use clusters when necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best practice in any mapping situation where you have that many markers is to use marker clustering.

e.g.

https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster
http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.markercluster/example/marker-clustering-realworld.388.html